# Constrained Minimization of a Quadratic Form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, numerical-optimization

I am formulating and solving an optimization problem in which the objective function seems to be in the form of $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{O}\mathbf{x}$. If it were an unconstrained optimization the minimizer of this objective function would have been an eigenvector of $\mathbf{O}$ corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue. However, this would not work for my case for two reasons, 1) the minimum eigenvalue is negative and that is not acceptable, and 2) the norm of $\mathbf{x}$ is to be bounded by a linear constraint in the form of $\boldsymbol{\rho}^T\mathbf{x}\leq m$. The matrix $\mathbf{O}$ is highly asymmetrical and in square shape. Does anyone have any idea for producing an elegant algebraic formulation or a solution procedure to this problem as a generalized eigen-decomposition problem?

Comment: First thing: because you have a quadratic form, you can symmetrize the matrix by taking $\frac{1}{2}(O + O^T)$. Have you tried writing down the KKT conditions?

Comment: thanks for your comment @CharlieVanaret! Unfortunately, making the matrix symmetric would render the objective function meaningless. The matrix $\mathbf{O}$ represents a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) in this case.  Do you see a specific challenge because of the asymmetric matrix other than the eigenvalues and eigen vectors being complex numbers? I haven't attempted writing the KKT conditions explicitly yet. I have just assumed that the problem is convex so far. How would you go about doing that?

Comment: I must add  that my expectation to use the eigenvectors of this matrix directly for optimization is perhaps not relevant because it is not positive or negative definite.